# Reflection: Set a property of a generic object using delegates

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm working on a simple ORM library, quite simple in fact...

I have a query of type T

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string query)
```

The method takes the T class, it gets the properties, loops through them and sets them accordingly

```
aProperty.SetValue(tmpGenericObjectOfTypeT, newValue, null);
```

My problem is that SetValue is incredibly slow, I saw two alternatives, using Reflection.Emit, or using delegates, unfortunately I have no idea how to do any of those.

As I've read, using delegates is a bit more elegant, and I'd like that solution, but I don't really know how to do it, I've searched and found a lot on how to call methods using Delegates, but not how to set properties...

Comment: Unless you already know the name of your property delegates won't really help you. Since you want to do this at runtime you are stuck with either reflection or meta-programming via Reflection.Emit, or using ExpressionTrees. Neither are pleasant, but you if you want more performance then you are going to have to bite the bullet.

Comment: Looks like emit it is. Thanks. Wouldn't it work if I make them implement a base class, so I know the name of the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamic methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9.aspx) or [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) which know how to get/set the property are the way to go here. Fast and easy.

- Examine the interface of your type using reflection
- Build getter/setter `Actions/Funcs` and cache them in an object which relates them to the original type.
- Used cached getters/setters in subsequent operations.

You should see at least a 20x performance improvement over reflection (if not more like 50-100x).

Comment: Looks like Expression Trees don't use Emit, that would be a nice option for me as I have no idea hwo to use it. Thanks a lot! Any tips on where I can read more about expression trees?

Comment: The link I included is a good start, and there are at least a few expression tree gurus here on SO. If you can't find an existing answer, just open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

HyperDescriptor works pretty well (ReflectionEmit based).
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18450/HyperDescriptor-Accelerated-dynamic-property-acces

The "delegate" method is probably referring to expression trees?

Comment: If you go with HyperDescriptor on .net4 this might be needed.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105763/does-hyperdescriptor-work-when-built-in-net-4