# Reflection: Setting properties of lots of objects using Dynamic Methods

Tags: c#, reflection

So I have thousands of objects, of generic type T, and I want to cast them to an array of objects I got.
So I have to get the properties list T, and for each property set the value to the corresponding object on the array

```
for (int i = 0; reader.Read(); i++)
{
    T tmp = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {         
        prop.SetValue(tmp, reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(prop.Name)), null);
    }
}
```

reader is a DataReader. The problem I have is that *prop.SetValue* is sadly slow (consumes like 50% of the total excecution time), [I've been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611551/reflection-set-a-property-of-a-generic-object-using-delegates) to use Dynamic Methods or Expression Trees, I tried using expression trees but from what I understood I have to generate one tree for each value I want to set, which wouldn't be so good.
So Dynamic Methods is the other option. Ideally I'd need to create a method *SetProp(object, propertyName, value)* which I can reuse over and over again.

Comment: *personally*, I would say "don't use GetOrdinal per cell", although it isn't going to matter much - however, since this is clearly "data-reader" code that has a 1:1 match between property name and column name, I really suggest you look at dapper-dot-net; it is designed for **exactly** this scenario, and makes data access just painless. It is the tool we wrote and use extensively for the majority of our data-access here at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [FastMember](http://code.google.com/p/fast-member/); either use it "as is", or steal all the code (`DynamicMethod`, etc). It does all this, with reflection-cache etc built in. Example usage:

```
var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(T)); 
for (int i = 0; reader.Read(); i++)
{
    T tmp = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {         
        accessor[tmp, propName] = newValue; // fill in name/value here
    }
}
```

alternatively - use something like dapper-dot-net, that does that *and* handles all the materialization (since this is obviously data-access code).

Comment: Only +1 cause I can't vote 10 times, from a quick look it works great...I **must** update my code!

Comment: There's also `ObjectAccessor` for that object-by-object code; I should also note that it supports the `dynamic` API too (so you can use it to talk to a runtime-property-bound object)

Answer (score 3):

> I tried using expression trees but from what I understood I have to generate one tree for each value I want to set, which wouldn't be so good.

Why not? You'd basically build a `List<Tuple<string, Action<object>>>` by creating (and then compiling) an expression tree for each property in `T`. Then you iterate over the list and fetch the item for each property, then call the corresponding action.

I have a `PropertyCopy` class in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) which does something very similar - you may want to look at that for inspiration.

Alternatively, as of .NET 4 you could build a single `Block` expression tree which does *all* the property setting.

Comment: I don't think I use that solution but I will definitely check that too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single expression tree for each property.
Just take the value as a parameter:

```
var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
var setter = Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.SetProperty(instance, Expression.Cast(value, prop.PropertyType)),
    instance, value
);
```

You would create and compile these expression trees once per instance type (typically in a [static generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686630/34397)).

While you're at it, you can probably make it even faster by compiling another expression tree instead of `Activator.CreateInstance()`.